# How to prevent angular behavior on anchor element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, anchor

I have an html page with the following anchor line:

```
<a href="#help" class="button scrolly">
```

In the same page - when I click on this anchor my page scrolls to the following section:

```
<section id="signup">
```

The scrolly class is a jquery pluging for making the page scrolling to the section. Now, angular change the behavior of the anchor and when I click on the link - it search for a route called 'help'. How I prevent this behavior and make the anchor just use it's regular HTML behavior?

I tried to change the href from #help to ##help - but it makes the page jump and not implement the scrolly class script.

I tried to override the anchor by directive and using a regular jquery scrolling (ignoring the scrolly class) by using the following code:

```
app.directive('a', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            if (attrs.href === '#help') {
                elem.on('click', function (e) {
                    var target = $(this.href);
                    if (target.length) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: target.offset().top
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

but it does not work.

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Replace: `var target = $(this.href);` with `var target = $(this);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer - I had a bug on my directive - it should be:

```
app.directive('a', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            if (attrs.href === '#help') {
                elem.on('click', function (e) {
                    var target = $(attrs.href);
                    if (target.length) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: target.offset().top
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

I used the attr.href as the jQuery DOM element name.

Anyway - if there is another simpler answer I would link to know it.

Thanks.